# Is there a way for me to change the color of specific text in a C program in DevC++?

Tags: c, winapi, colors, console

Basically, I'm working on this text editor program for a school project that uses simple filing and string functions to create, append, delete, display, duplicate, or search from text files. I've managed to put all the functions together, and my question pertains to my `Search()` function, which I'll attach at the end of this for reference. If the search keyword is found, the function prints which line it was found in, and it prints the line itself. What I'd like to do is, if possible, change the color of the search keyword when the line gets printed so that it stands out and the user can immediately tell where his keyword is located within the line. I'm not asking this without doing ANY research on the matter; I did some digging and it seems I can make use of ANSI escape sequences or the Windows Console Virtual Terminal Sequences to achieve what I'm trying to do, and I did go through the documentation on the Microsoft website, but unfortunately I'm not yet comfortable with calling windows APIs and I could really use some help figuring out exactly how to go about doing this. Also, apologies in advance if the code I'm attaching seems inefficient or unncessary at times, only started learning C a couple months ago. I am using the gcc compiler with DevC++ on Windows 10.
TIA.

```
void Search(void) {
    FILE *fptr;
    char name[20], key[30], line[100];
    int linenum=1, found=0;
    printf("Enter name of text file to search from, or enter 'exit' to cancel and return to menu: ");
    gets(name);
    if(strcmp(name,"exit") == 0)
        return;
    strcat(name,".txt");
    fptr = fopen(name,"r");
    while(!fptr) {                                  // just some input validation
        printf("Error. Text file not found. Make sure it exists and is placed in the same folder as the .exe file for this program.");
        fclose(fptr);
        printf("\n\nEnter name of text file to search from, or enter 'exit' to cancel and return to menu: ");
        gets(name);
        if(strcmp(name,"exit") == 0)
            return;
        strcat(name,".txt");
        fptr = fopen(name,"r"); 
    }
    printf("Enter your search keyword (remember, it is case sensitive): "); //searching staarts here
    gets(key);
    while(!feof(fptr)) {
        fgets(line,100,fptr);
        if(strstr(line,key)) {
            printf("Keyword found in line %d:\n", linenum);
            printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            printf("%s",line);
            printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
            found=1;
        }
        linenum++;
    }
    if(!found) 
        printf("Keyword not found in file.");
    printf("\nPress any key to return to main menu: ");
    getch();
}
```

The reason I used the long ------------ separators is that I want to differentiate the contents of a text file from the contents of what's written in the console window.

Comment: Depending on your console you can use the [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Comment: Also called [Virtual Terminal Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences).

Comment: Yeah I did run into these while researching how to do this, it's just I couldn't quite find a simple enough answer as to how to actually implement them in my code. Really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can rely on string class to complete this task, use `string :: find` to extract the location of the key, and then use `string:: substr` to print the value of the key.

Refer to the code below:

```
void Search(void) {
    ...
    printf("Enter your search keyword (remember, it is case sensitive): "); //searching staarts here
    gets_s(key);
    while (!feof(fptr)) {
        fgets(line, 100, fptr);
        if (strstr(line, key)) {
            std::string str(line);
            printf("Keyword found in line %d:\n", linenum);
            printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            int pos = str.find(key);
            int len = strlen(key);
            int len_t = strlen(line);
            if (pos != 0)
            {
                printf("%s", str.substr(0, pos).c_str());
                printf("\x1b[31m%s", str.substr(pos, len).c_str());
                printf("\x1b[0m%s\r\n", str.substr(len+pos, len_t).c_str());
            } 
            else
            {
                 printf("\x1b[31m%s", str.substr(pos, len).c_str());
                 printf("\x1b[0m%s\r\n", str.substr(pos+len, len_t).c_str());
            }           
            printf("\x1b[0m----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");
            found = 1;
        }
        linenum++;
    }
    if (!found)
        printf("Keyword not found in file.");
    printf("\nPress any key to return to main menu: ");
    getch();
}
```

Debug:
[image]

Comment: Woah, that's amazing. That's exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could simply use the [Windows API console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-screen-buffers#character-attributes):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
  HANDLE hstdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hstdout, FOREGROUND_RED|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
  printf("hello ");
  SetConsoleTextAttribute(hstdout, FOREGROUND_GREEN|FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
  printf("world");
  return 0;
}
```